# Grant access to project via another project in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, odbc, roles, service-accounts

I have some views in a GCP project: project1, I created a service account with json keys in another GCP project: project2.
I granted data editor role on the SA that were created in project2 to access data in project1.
I have an external application: ODBC that needs to access data in project1 via the SA that was created in project2.

I am getting an access error when trying to query data in project1 from the ODBC using the SA that was created in project2

try to access data in project1 using SA in project2 in the ODBC

Comment: You cannot grant permission to project1 from project2. You must add the service account email address to IAM in project1. Only project1 can grant access to an identity (service account). The service account can be from any project.

Comment: thank you for you response @JohnHanley, so I should create the SA in project1 with the needed roles? do I have to create the SA at project level (in the IAM part) or is sharing the dataset enough (giving bigquery data owner on the dataset)?
also, do I have to generate the json key for the ODBC to be able to access the views ?

Comment: What was described in the question should work, assuming that the "data editor" role was set in project 1 and that this gives sufficient permissions for what you are trying to do

Comment: The data editor role was set on the dataset level and on project level, does it make a difference ?

Comment: Hi `Mariem Riahi` can you edit the question and draft all your queries at one place as it will help us in framing a relevant answer for you and for your last query yes it will make the difference. 

If you have given access to a particular dataset the user can view or edit only that dataset if you have provided that at project level the user can view or edit all the datasets present in the project.